# Trying to return a 2d array from a method

Tags: c#, arrays, return

Making a Hangman game. I want in this function to take the 'Answer' which has been validated elsewhere in my code and split it into its individual letters and then Hangman equivalent representative.
e.g.:

```
abc == ___   
hi world == __/_____ and so on..
```

I am using a 2d array 'UncoveredArray' to hold this data. I want to now return it to my main so that it can be used for the next step of the game in another method.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    NewGame Hangman = new NewGame();
    string Answer = Hangman.GetWord();
    
    var UncoveredArray = new char[Answer.Length, 2];       

    UncoveredArray = Hangman.ProcessWord(Answer, out UncoveredArray);
```

```cs
public char[] ProcessWord(string Answer, out char UncoveredArray)
{
    char[] chars = Answer.ToCharArray();
    var UncoveredArray = new char[chars.Length, 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < Answer.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] == ' ')
        {
            Console.Write("/");
            UncoveredArray[i, 0] = chars[i];
            UncoveredArray[i, 1] = '/';
        }
        else if (char.IsPunctuation(chars[i]))
        {
            Console.Write(chars[i]);
            UncoveredArray[i, 0] = chars[i];
            UncoveredArray[i, 1] = chars[i];
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("_");

            UncoveredArray[i, 0] = chars[i];
            UncoveredArray[i, 1] = '_';
        }
    }
    return UncoveredArray;
    //TODO: RETURN ARRAY 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion arises from unnecessary use of an `out` parameter. Out params allow for args to be passed in by reference, while also allowing them to be initialized inline. This is different from a `ref` param which strictly is a pass by reference, that argument must have been initialized previously. One key usage of out parameters is with the `.TryParse()` methods, which return a boolean flag to show if the parse was successful, and if it was, you get the parsed variable "out" of it.

Simplify things: just return a new instance

```cs
public char[,] ProcessWord(string answer) {} //logic remains more or less the same

//in Main() use it like
char[,] uncoveredArray = hangman.ProcessWord(answer);
```

Notice in your original method, you pass in the `char[,] UncoveredArray` as an output parameter and then *immediately* cobbler it with `var UncoveredArray = new char[chars.Length, 2];`. This won't compile, and if it did, it would make the the out param pointless in the first place. Be careful, you never want to attempt to initialize a new variable with the same name, especially when its taking on the name of a parameter. As far as I know C# doesn't support something like Rust/F# etc.'s "shadowing" which allows such a phenomenon

Also the return type must be `char[,]` not `char[]`. The 1st is an actual 2D array, while the 2nd is 1D

Use of explicit typing, rather than `var` helps out a lot in cases like this, it would've help you catch this error a bit easier. Please be sure to follow proper naming conventions for variables, classes, and methods as well

Comment: This worked great. Changed the char[] to char[,] and removed the out and then changed the call. Commented out the other code and it worked like a treat.  I then tested that the values were passed correctly. Thank you!!